# After data migration it is happening when i click on any product link in magento 2.2.0?

Tags: magento2.2.0, data-migration

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'reference': This element is not expected.
Line: 1309

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto the admin panel and edit the product you are having issues. And remove the design update filed with an empty value and save & reindex.

It comes from the Magento1 table. not supported in 2.